# ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10. How to fix alphanumeric values?

Tags: javascript, python, maps

I am working with a code which gives me the X,Y Coordinates and plot numbers in map.Ex: plot number 20,21,22 etc. But if the map had alpha-numeric values like 20-A,20A or 20 A,I am stuck because when I input the value like 20-A i get this error "ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10". So please help me how to handle alpha-numeric values.

Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk
import tkSimpleDialog

#Add path of map file here. The output will be saved in the same path with name map_file_name.extension.csv
path = "maps/21.jpg"


#Set this to true for verbose output in the console
debug = False


#Window for pop ups
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.lift()
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',False)


#Global and state variables
global_state = 1
xcord_1, ycord_1, xcord_2, ycord_2 = -1,-1,-1,-1
edge1, edge2 = -1,-1

#Defining Plot
img = Image.open(path)
img = img.convert('RGB')
img = np.array(img)

if(debug):
    print "Image Loaded; dimensions = "
    print img.shape

#This let us bind the mouse function the plot
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
fig = plt.gcf()
#Selecting tight layout
fig.tight_layout()
#Plotting Image
imgplot = ax.imshow(img)

#Event listener + State changer
def onclick(event):
    global xcord_1,xcord_2,ycord_1,ycord_2,edge1,edge2, imgplot,fig, ax, path
    if(debug):
        print "Single Click Detected"
        print "State = " + str(global_state)
    if event.dblclick:
        if(debug):
            print "Double Click Detection"
        global global_state
        if(global_state==0):


            xcord_1 = event.xdata
            ycord_1 = event.ydata

            edge1 = (tkSimpleDialog.askstring("2nd", "No of 2nd Selected Plot"))
            #Draw here
            if edge1 is None: #Incase user cancels the pop up. Go to initial state
                global_state = 1
                pass
            else:
                edge1 = int(edge1)
                global_state = 1
                difference = edge2-edge1
                dif_state = 1;
                #So difference is always positive. Dif_state keeps track of plot at which side has the larger number
                if difference <0:
                    dif_state = -1;
                    difference *= -1
                #Corner Case; labelling a single plot
                if(difference == 0):
                    import csv
                    fields = [int(xcord_1),int(ycord_1),edge1]
                    plt.scatter(int(xcord_1),int(ycord_1),marker='$' + str(edge1) + '$', s=150)
                    with open(path+'.csv', 'a') as f:
                        writer = csv.writer(f)
                        writer.writerow(fields)
                else:
                    if(debug):
                        print "P1 : (" + str(xcord_1) + ", " + str(ycord_1) + " )"
                        print "P2 : (" + str(xcord_2) + ", " + str(ycord_2) + " )"
                    for a in range(0,difference+1):
                        #Plotting the labels
                        plt.scatter(int(xcord_1+(a*(float(xcord_2-xcord_1)/difference))),int(ycord_1+a*((float(ycord_2-ycord_1)/difference))),marker='$'+str(edge1+dif_state*a)+'$',s=150)
                        #Saving in CSV
                        import csv
                        fields = [int(xcord_1+(a*(float(xcord_2-xcord_1)/difference))),int(ycord_1+a*((float(ycord_2-ycord_1)/difference))),str(edge1+dif_state*a)]
                        with open(path+'.csv', 'a') as f:
                            writer = csv.writer(f)
                            writer.writerow(fields)

                        if debug:
                            print (int(xcord_1+(a*(float(xcord_2-xcord_1)/difference))),int(ycord_1+a*((float(ycord_2-ycord_1)/difference))))
                plt.show()



        elif(global_state == 1):
            xcord_2 = event.xdata
            ycord_2 = event.ydata
            print "Recorded"
            edge2 = (tkSimpleDialog.askstring("1st", "No of Selected Plot"))
            print type(edge2)
            if edge2 is None:
                root.withdraw()
                pass
            else:
                edge2 = int(edge2)
                global_state = 0



cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the value is "20-A"? Do you want to convert that to the integer "20"?

Comment: no i want to input the exact value i.e. "20-A" but when i type 20-A then i got error. Now i can input only integer and i want to input both integers and alpha-numeric values

Comment: What if you type "20-A2"? What number do you expect to get? 20? 202? a list of 20,2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function to separate 20-A into 20 and A.

For example, `"20-A".split('-')` will return `['20','A']`.  You can then call the `int` method on the first element of this array

Comment: thanku sir can u tell me where to use this function as i am new to this or make changes and get me the code with changes made working code.

Answer (score 0):

Generic way will be to use [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract digit from the text.

For example:

```
import re

def get_number_from_string(my_str):
    return re.findall('\d+', my_str)
```

This will extract all the numbers from the string and return as a `list`.

In case you need just one value, extract the number at index `0`. Sample run:

```
>>> get_number_from_string('20-A')
['20']
>>> get_number_from_string('20 A')
['20']
>>> get_number_from_string('20A')
['20']
```

Hence, your code to convert the number string to `int` should be like:

```
number_string = get_number_from_string('20A')[0]  # For getting only 1st number from list
number = int(number_string)  # Type-cast it to int
```

Comment: Thanku so much for ur answer can you plz make changes in the code and  post please.

Comment: I haven't checked your entire code. I answered your question: *"But if the map had alpha-numeric values like 20-A,20A or 20 A,I am stuck because when I input the value like 20-A"* It is your code, you know where to put this :)